# How to get related data using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im looking to find some smarter way to get related book description using IQueryable.

```
IQueryable list = db.Students.Select(x => new StudentsViewModel
        {
            StudentID = x.StudentID,
            Name = x.Name,
            BookID = x.BookID,
            DescriptionForBookByBookID = db.Books.Where(v => v.BookID == x.BookID).Select(v => v.Description).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
        });
```

Thanks for any advice ;)

Comment: What do you mean by smarter?

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up between Students and Books in your model?  Are you using Entity Framework? (if so, tag it)

Comment: Any other approach would be nice also.

Comment: Yes, a have a relation and yes entity is taged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define navigation property for `Book` in `Student` entity:

```
public int StudentID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int? BookID { get; set; } // assume book is optional, but you can use int
public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
```

And use it to get book description for your view model:

```
db.Students.Select(s => new StudentsViewModel
{
    StudentID = s.StudentID,
    Name = s.Name,
    BookID = s.BookID,
    DescriptionForBookByBookID = s.Book.Description
})
```

Generated query will look like

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[StudentID] AS [StudentID],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent1].[BookID] AS [BookID],
    [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM  [dbo].[Students] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent2] 
        ON [Extent1].[BookID] = [Extent2].[BookID]
```

Comment: I'm guessing Students can have more than one book (not that his model reflects that, having BookID defined)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh then why student has BookID foreign key?

Comment: yep, spotted that.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that looks better